# SQL Server 2008 Combine or test rows based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+--------+
|  emplname  |  JAN    |  FEB   |   MAR   |   APR  |   MAY  |
+------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+--------+
|   ALLEN    |   NULL  |  NULL  |   17    |   17   |   17   |
|   ALLEN    |   17    |  17    |   205   |   NULL |  NULL  |  
|   ADAMS    |   NULL  |  NULL  |   14    |   14   |   17   |
|   BROWN    |   NULL  |  205   |   13    |   13   |   13   |
|   BROWN    |   12    |  12    |   NULL  |   NULL |   NULL |
+------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+--------+
```

I want to combine the rows where the emplname is the same and ignoring 205 values, so for ALLEN, I would get

```
|   ALLEN    |   17    |  17    |   17    |   17   |   17   |
```

for BROWN it would be

```
|   BROWN    |   12    |  12    |   13    |   13   |   13   |
```

Basically what I want to do is be able to find if, per employee, if a column has two entries for it except if it is an entry plus 205, i can ignore 205.  What I want to find is something like this:

```
|   BROWN    |   NULL  |  13    |   13    |   13   |   13   |
|   BROWN    |   12    |  12    |   NULL  |   NULL |   NULL |
```

where that third column has 13 and 12 for that one employee. I am looking for things like that.  if it exists, return the emplname. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: do you want the result you posted or the emplname?

Comment: To be honest, either way.  Probably best to just get the emplname that meet that criteria.  So BROWN would be returned, the others wouldnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this (I think I am understanding you correctly, this will output names of employees who need two rows)

```
SELECT emplname FROM yourtable
GROUP BY emplname
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN JAN = 205 THEN NULL ELSE JAN END) > 1 OR
COUNT(CASE WHEN FEB = 205 THEN NULL ELSE FEB END) > 1 OR
COUNT(CASE WHEN MAR = 205 THEN NULL ELSE MAR END) > 1 OR
COUNT(CASE WHEN APR = 205 THEN NULL ELSE APR END) > 1 OR
COUNT(CASE WHEN MAY = 205 THEN NULL ELSE MAY END) > 1
```

Let me know if that was what you have in mind; I think it answers the second part of the question.

Comment: You can replace `CASE WHEN JAN = 205 THEN NULL ELSE JAN END` with `NULLIF(JAN, 205)` for each month -- oops, I see it has been mentioned again in another answer

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself and then use the following statement

```
COALESCE(CASE WHEN table1.fieldname = 205 THEN NULL ELSE table1.fieldname END,
         CASE WHEN table2.fieldname = 205 THEN NULL ELSE table2.fieldname END,0)
```

I use 0 here to mark an error but you could leave it out so you get null when you have a problem.

Comment: you can use `NULLIF(fieldname,205)` instead of `CASE WHEN fieldname = 205 THEN NULL ELSE fieldname END`

Comment: @Lamak, I could have but I chose to use standard SQL which will have the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL:

```
SELECT T.emplname 
    , ISNULL(T.JAN,IIF(T205.JAN=205,NULL,T205.JAN)) 
    , ISNULL(T.FEB,IIF(T205.FEB=205,NULL,T205.FEB)) 
    , ISNULL(T.MAR,IIF(T205.MAR=205,NULL,T205.MAR)) 
    , ISNULL(T.APR,IIF(T205.APR=205,NULL,T205.APR)) 
    , ISNULL(T.MAY,IIF(T205.MAY=205,NULL,T205.MAY))
FROM myTable as T left join myTable as T205 on  T.emplname = T205.emplname 
    AND (T.JAN <> 205 AND T.FEB <> 205 AND T.MAR <> 205 
           AND T.APR <> 205 AND T.MAY <> 205)
    AND (T205.JAN = 205 OR T205.FEB = 205 OR T205.MAR = 205 
           OR T205.APR = 205 OR T205.MAY = 205)
```